# Meaning of a name: "Baute"

Tags: étymologie, noms-de-famille

In trying to find out what's in my family name "Baute" (which is quite uncommon in Germany), I recently [found strong hints pointing to southern france](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12631), the Midi-Pyrénées to be exact.

But I am still looking for the etymology of the name, i.e. what it might mean or what word it had been derived of.

Spelling variants are "Ibaute" or "Bauter". Given the area and the fact that it dates back well into medieval times, the roots of the name could well be occitan.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Did you  try googling it ? First hit :http://www.geneanet.org/genealogie/fr/baute.html

Comment: This should to go http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Bregalad: I understand why this question might *also* be suitable for that site. I also see where jlliagre's anser is sourced by genealogy websites. But as I was asking about the etymology of a (most likely) French name / word, I don't feel I was wrong in coming here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'origine est incertaine, il pourrait s'agir d'un nom de [lieu](http://www.jeantosti.com/noms/b3.htm)

Il y a aussi des [Baute](http://users.belgacom.net/oscar.vandecavey/dat0.htm#598) à Bruges en Belgique au début du XVIIIème siècle.

Comment: Infos nom commun : [etym](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=baut), [baute](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baute), [baud](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/baud), [baud dmf](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/baud?idf=dmfXgXrmXbcaj;str=0).